# Counting the number of selected rows on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following code to count the number of selected rows in a table (tableview1).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    int count = 0;
    selectedindex1 = indexPath.row;
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in tableview1.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    rowcount = count;
}
```

where selectedindex1 and rowcount are integer variables.

This code works as long as you assume that the user won't select a row that has already been selected.  If they do, the application can't tell the right number of selected rows because such an action won't trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  Is there a better way of counting the number of selected rows?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If a row is already selected, you can't select it again, can you? And even if you could, it wouldn't affect the number of selected rows. What exactly are you trying to do with your row count variable?

Comment: I failed to mention, but 'Multiple Selection' is enabled.  Sorry about that...

Comment: That was clear enough. I didn't understand that you wanted to act on deselection as well as selection. What do you use the rowcount variable for anyway? Why not just use an outlet to keep a reference to the tableview and invoke `-indexPathsForSelectedRows` in your code when you need the count?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's as simple as this:

```
[[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count]
```

Then again, that's exactly what your code does:

```
int count = 0;
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in tableview1.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
    count = count + 1;
}
rowcount = count;
```

What is it exactly that you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks.  You've reduced the number of lines.  But the same problem persists.

Comment: did you mean indexPathsForSelectedRows?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just keep a running array of the indexPath's that are selected..That way, you won't ever have to worry about selecting the same one twice.

-Initialize an array in viewDidLoad

```
  NSMutableArray *yourSelectedRowsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

-And then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath...do something like this:

```
if(![yourSelectedRowsArray containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [yourSelectedRowsArray addObject:indexPath];
}

NSLog(@"the number of selected rows is %d",yourSelectedRowsArray.count);
```

-And in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath..do something like:

```
if([yourSelectedRowsArray containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [yourSelectedRowsArray removeObject:indexPath];
    }

NSLog(@"the number of selected rows now is %d",yourSelectedRowsArray.count);
```

Then just access the count of the array wherever you want to use it, and you'll have the number of selected rows.

Comment: Since UITableView keeps track of the selected index paths for you, this seems pointless.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know there's a deselect method as well.

Comment: haha wow hmmm i guess it helped the poster... @TBlue no problem man

Answer (score 2):

Okay.  It's as simple as the following.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    rowcount =  [[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    rowcount =  [[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count];
}
```